# How can I dynamically read streamed/pushed data from a webpage with java or Python?

Tags: javascript, java, python, http, stream

I am looking for the best approach that can help me to fetch/receive a Push Stream (e.g. lightstreamer) from a Web-Page.

It is not possible to program a crawler for this as the website updates a Table via JavaScript every 5 seconds, it is dynamically loaded.

I want this Table of data from this web page, but I do not know how I can do this with Java or Python. I have searched a lot and most answers are for questions like “How to stream data from the server” but what I want is the exact opposite, how can I read dynamically streamed/pushed data from a web page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to retrieve the web page.

Then parse the response every 5sec.

Comment: for that i have to keep the connection alive i think. it wouldn't make much sense to make 17280 requests per day. I dont think that Requests is the right technologie for my problem, but i will give it a try. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like their [JavaScript Client Library](http://www.lightstreamer.com/repo/distros/Lightstreamer_Allegro-Presto-Vivace_6_0_3_20160905.zip%23/Lightstreamer/DOCS-SDKs/sdk_client_web_unified/doc/API-reference/index.html) is what you want.  If you program it in Python or Java you'll just be moving the problem to the server side and still need an answer on the web side.